# Java best practice: optimum number of calls in the Controller

Tags: java, servlets, model-view-controller

We have an internal website with dozens of reports for the user to choose from.  These go to a Reports Servlet with is the controller.  It contains code such as:

```
if (report.equals('reportOne')){
   bo.runReportOne(requestObjectData);
} else if(report.equals('reportTwo')){
   bo.runReportTwo(requestObjectData);
}
```

How many of these if/else are optimal before breaking things apart.  For example having multiple servlets based on function.  For example ProcessReportsServlet, ResultReportsServlet, BillingReportServlet, etc.

Thanks,
Brita

Comment: In general this logic should not be in the Controller. It's preferred to have a Service class (for ex. GenerateReportService) and pass the request details to it. The Service should read the report "name"(?) like - 'reportOne' - should retrieve/generate reportOne and send it back to the Controller, which will send in as a response to the user.

Comment: Also you should avoid having a new method for each separate report. Try to create a generic service method, which accepts reportName and other needed info, and returns the desired report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, if you know you are going to be adding to this list *eventually* you should plan to clean up the if-else chain you'll create, or clean it up right now. You probably also want to figure out a different approach than having a new method for each type of report you can possibly create. I think anything less than 5 if-else statements is fine.

Comment: 5 or 6 is the max I've heard. For cleanup, consider using an `enum`, even if you don't go full MVC-service-DAO just yet.